# Null Error with eWAY iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-gateway, payment

I am currently writing an iOS application utilising a credit card SDK from a company called eWAY.

I am attempting to get it working in a sandbox test environment but I keep receiving a null error.

**NSLog output (The "EWAY ERROR" is part of my NSLog message)**

```
2015-10-15 12:25:40.127 EwayTest[1351:37919] EWAY ERROR: <null> ()
```

Im literally using the example on the webpage: https://www.eway.com.au/developers/sdk/ios

Gateway:
I am using the URL: https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/ gateway as specified.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)btnPress:(id)sender
{
    Transaction *transaction = [[Transaction alloc] init];

    Customer *customerObj = [[Customer alloc] init];
    customerObj.Reference = @"A12345";
    customerObj.Title = @"Mr.";
    customerObj.FirstName = @"Nico";
    customerObj.LastName = @"Vulture";
    customerObj.CompanyName = @"All Web Pty Ltd";
    customerObj.JobDescription = @"Developer";
    customerObj.Phone = @"09 889 0986";
    customerObj.Mobile = @"09 889 0986";

    Address *customerAddress = [[Address alloc] init];
    customerAddress.Street1 = @"Level 5";
    customerAddress.Street2 = @"369 Queen Street";
    customerAddress.City = @"Sydney";
    customerAddress.State = @"NSW";
    customerAddress.PostalCode = @"2010";
    customerAddress.Country = @"au";

    customerObj.Address = customerAddress;

    CardDetails *cardDetails = [[CardDetails alloc] init];
    cardDetails.Name = @"Nico Vulture";
    cardDetails.Number = @"378282246310005";
    cardDetails.ExpiryMonth = @"10";
    cardDetails.ExpiryYear = @"19";
    cardDetails.CVN = @"836";
    customerObj.CardDetails = cardDetails;

    transaction.Customer = customerObj;

    //payment
    Payment *payment = [[Payment alloc] init];
    payment.Payment = 100;
    payment.InvoiceNumber = @"Inv 21540";
    payment.InvoiceDescription = @"Individual Invoice Description";
    payment.InvoiceReference = @"513456";
    payment.CurrencyCode = @"AUD";

    transaction.Payment = payment;

    //Make payment
    [RapidAPI submitPayment:transaction completed:^(SubmitPaymentResponse *submitPaymentResponse) {

        if(submitPaymentResponse.Status == Accepted)
        {
            NSLog(@"EWAY: Accepted");
        }
        else if (submitPaymentResponse.Status == Success)
        {
            // The API Call completed successfully.
            NSLog(@"EWAY: Success");
        }
        else if(submitPaymentResponse.Status == Error)
        {
            // An error occurred with the API Call.
            [RapidAPI userMessage:submitPaymentResponse.Errors Language:@"EN" completed:^(UserMessageResponse *userMessageResponse) {
                NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@",userMessageResponse.Errors, userMessageResponse.Messages];
                NSLog(@"EWAY ERROR: %@",msg);
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

I have however noticed when I change up the gateway (URL) https://api.ewaypayments.com/DirectPayment.json I get an error output of:

```
EWAY ERROR: S9990 
 (null)
```

Which as on the website indicates a "Library does not have Endpoint initialised, or not initialise to a URL" error.

I have been in contact with the company, it must be me doing something wrong here. Has anyone had any experience with this and could provide some insight as to what I'm missing?

Comment: i was facing same problem , i just change sandbox api to live (production) api it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update anyone who is or was experiencing this problem. The code works perfectly there was a bug in the SDK that has since been fixed.